# Expand flex container respective to its children with flex grow

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a container that has fixed width and inside that I have a flexible menu with `display: flex`

I want the menu-list to grow upto `max-width: 420px`, and if it reaches max-width it should wrap and display in next line, so I can't use  `white-space: nowrap` which makes my menu-list scrollable if it exceeds 420px. How can I make the parent menu expand proportionally with menu-list. The red background should expand 420px in the example below.

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 180px;
}

.menu {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.menu-list {
  margin: 10px;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  max-width: 420px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-list">
      <div class="option">1. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
      <div class="option">2. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
      <div class="option">3. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
      <div class="option">4. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `.menu-list` has a maximum width of 420px, then why not just give `.menu` the same maximum?

Then make the top level wrapper a flex container and disable shrinking on `.menu`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 180px;
  border: 2px dashed black;
}

.menu {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  max-width: 420px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.menu-list {}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-list">
      <div class="option">1. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
      <div class="option">2. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea using `width: max-content;` (that will not work on IE: https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_width_max-content)

```css
.container {
  padding: 10px;
  margin:5px;
  max-width: 180px;  
}
.menu {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
.menu-list {
  margin: 10px;
  width:max-content;
  max-width: 420px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-list">
      <div class="option">1. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
      <div class="option">2. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
      <div class="option">3. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
      <div class="option">4. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-list">
      <div class="option">1. The quick  brown fox jumps over the lazy dog brown fox jump s over the lazy dog</div>
      <div class="option">2. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
      <div class="option">3. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
      <div class="option">4. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-list">
      <div class="option">1. The quick  brown fox</div>
      <div class="option">2. The quick brown </div>
      <div class="option">3. The quick bro</div>
      <div class="option">4. The qui</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another idea using CSS grid.

```css
.container {
  padding: 10px;
  margin:5px;
  max-width: 180px;  
}
.menu {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-auto-columns: max-content;
}
.menu-list {
  margin: 10px;
  max-width: 420px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-list">
      <div class="option">1. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
      <div class="option">2. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
      <div class="option">3. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
      <div class="option">4. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-list">
      <div class="option">1. The quick  brown fox jumps over the lazy dog brown fox jump s over the lazy dog</div>
      <div class="option">2. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
      <div class="option">3. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
      <div class="option">4. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-list">
      <div class="option">1. The quick  brown fox</div>
      <div class="option">2. The quick brown </div>
      <div class="option">3. The quick bro</div>
      <div class="option">4. The qui</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```